# Signification: « Qu'est-ce qu'ils sont cons? »

Tags: expressions, musique

J'ai entendu la phrase « Qu'est-ce qu'ils sont cons ? » dans une chanson.
En auriez-vous la signification ?

Comment: À noter qu'il ne s'agissait probablement pas d'une question, mais d'une constatation. Il ne faut donc pas de point d'interrogation, malgré la forme `qu'est-ce que`.

Comment: Cela nous aiderait de connaître la chanson pour deviner le contexte.

Answer (score 6):

Comme indiqué par Hakim dans les commentaires, la phrase « Qu'est-ce qu'ils sont cons. » semble plus être une exclamation qu'une interrogation.

Random a également remarqué que le sens habituel de « con » est plus ou moins équivalent au "dumb" anglais. A l'origine ce mot désigne le [sexe féminin](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/con#Fran.C3.A7ais).

Une autre manière de dire la même chose serait :

> « Comme ils sont cons ! »

ou alors simplement

> « Qu'ils sont cons ! »

Selon le contexte, « Qu'ils sont cons ! » peut vouloir dire plusieurs choses.

1. Selon moi, le premier sens évident est une plainte envers les personnes désignées. On pourrait paraphraser : « Ils sont vraiment idiots ! » ou « Ils ne sont pas très intelligents ! »
2. Un autre sens, indirect, pourrait être la constatation d'une forme d'humour. « Qu'est-ce qu'ils sont cons ! » pourrait donc se paraphraser ainsi : « Ils me font rire en jouant les idiots ». On retrouve ce sens quand après une blague l'interlocuteur répond « T'es con ! ».

Answer (score 2):

D'abord, "con" peut se traduire par "dumb", c'est utilisé dans le langage familier/courant.
Comme [Hakim](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/7672/hakim) le fait remarquer, malgré la présence du "est-ce que", ce n'est pas une question, mais une exclamation.
On peut dire ainsi :

> Mais qu'est-ce qu'ils sont cons !
>   Comment font-ils pour être aussi cons ?
>   Ils sont vraiment trop cons !
>   Quels cons !
>   Quelle bande de cons !
>   Regarde-moi ces cons !
>   Regarde-moi cette bande de cons !

Cette construction marque l'étonnement de la personne qui parle. On met aussi l'accent sur le fait qu'ils sont "très" cons.

N.B: "bande de cons" peut être remplacé par "bande de bras cassés", qui a la même connotation, c'est à dire qu'ils ne sont pas très malins.